# non-editable text field in the Webix combobox

Tags: user-interface, combobox, webix

Just started using Webix in my study project.
Definitely enjoy it, but wondering if there's a way to make text field in the `combo` control non-editable and leave the possibility to pick values? Or I've missed something? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use RichSelect control (Non-editable Combo Box ('richselect')).
See a sample here: http://docs.webix.com/samples/13_form/01_controls/11_richselect.html